# C# 4.0 -- how to create & use project config with VS2010 SP1

Tags: c#-4.0

I need to create a project config file(i.e. project.config or project.ini) so that I can later use it store the preference selected by the user. When the application launches, it will automatically load that config file and customize the application based on the previous settings.

Is there a good way to do this in C# 4.0?
I used to manually do all these labor work by manipulating a file in C++ and I expect to get a cleaner and easier solution with .NET.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For WinForms and WPF, consider using the [Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx) built-in. No need to roll your own, in this case. This is a way to create and store settings data on behalf of your application and your users.

- predefine the settings you'd like the user to be able to save. Let's say it's `WindowSize`, and `BackgroundImage`.
- access these properties like so:

```
//get the value of WindowSize which is a string  
string windowSize = Properties.Settings.Default.WindowSize;    
MessageBox.Show("WindowSize setting value is :" + windowSize );  

//set the new value of BackgroundImage
Properties.Settings.Default.BackgroundImage= "http://foo.org/bar.png";  
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();      //apply the changes to the settings file
```

This persists to `yourAppName.exe.config`.

Answer (score 1):

Not only in C#, the XML technologies are useful for these kind of task. You can create XML Schema that describes the format of you configuration file, then you can use `xsd.exe` to generate C# classes from this schema and then with a few lines of code you can serialize into/deserialize from an xml file.